# How can a Chrome extension's content script determine the injected page's referrer?

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

What is the best way to determine a page's referrer within the context of a content script in a Chrome extension?

It looks possible to intercept requests' headers using the [chrome.webRequest](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/webRequest.html) module, but it would then take some book-keeping and message-passing in order to get it into the content script.

That approach feels kludgy.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `document.referrer`?